# QuickContacts integration on Newer HTC phones

Tags: android, quickcontact

Our app integrates with the Quick Contacts Badge.  Click on the badge and our icon appears in the list of icons.

Or at least it does unless you run it on say, the latest android release for the HTC Desire HD (android 2.3.3, sense 2.1).  On these phones the icon just won't show up.  Facebook and Skype seem to still have the integration working though, so it isn't the case that HTC have simply broken it.  Equally, our stuff works great on other android 2.3.4 phones.

Anybody out there have a clue what trick I might need to get this working?

Thanks in advance

Phil

Comment: Did you ever solved this? I'm having the same problem...

Comment: No, unfortunately not.  We essentially gave up on contacts integration